# Multiple Combined "Or" Queries using Android Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

In Parse for Android, is it possible to AND multiple OR sub-queries? I've been attempting to combine two OR queries with no luck. From what I've researched, Parse may not have this capacity; I haven't been able to find anything to confirm/deny that, though.

For example, given a bunch of `List<ParseQuery>` objects, I'm finding that a similar setup as below only performs the queries associated with `myList1`. Is this a result of how Parse handles ORs?

```
ParseQuery myQuery = new ParseQuery("myTable");

// ...

myQuery = myQuery.or(myList1);
myQuery = myQuery.or(myList2);
myQuery = myQuery.or(myList3);

// ...

myQuery.findInBackground(myCallback);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it doesn't work that way. [ParseQuery.or()](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-compound) can only OR Parse queries.

```
ParseQuery myQuery1 = new ParseQuery("myTable");
myQuery1.whereContainedIn("key", myList1);

ParseQuery myQuery2 = new ParseQuery("myTable");
myQuery2.whereContainedIn("key", myList2);

List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
queries.add(myQuery1);
queries.add(myQuery2);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
```

Now the mainQuery is equal to `whereContainedIn(myList1 OR myList2)`.