# Compare a date with null value

Tags: android, date, parse-platform

I am showing some posts (created by the users) in an activity using a custom adapter. In the constructor of the custom adapter, I am using the following code to get the query result.

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Post");
query.whereWithinMiles("location_point", my_point, 500);
query.whereGreaterThan("expire_date", new Date());
return query;
```

**The target is** - the user can set an expire date with each post so that the post will no longer be visible after the expiration. I am trying to compare the **expire_date** column with **current time** for checking if the post is expired or not.

The line `query.whereGreaterThan("expire_date", new Date());` was added later. All the previously created rows has a **null** value in the **expire_date** column.

So each time I run the query, all the rows that **has a date object** in expire_date column **are being checked** according to the condition. The rows **having a null value** in expire_date column **are never returned**.

Note: The expire_date column is not a mandatory field (user can choose to leave it empty during creating a post).

Yes, I can set a default date for all the empty/null fields to compare with the expire date. But I was curious to know if there is a way so that I can either return all the rows having a null value or compare the current time with a null object with the `whereGreaterThan` condition?

Comment: Did you try an OR query?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892973/multiple-combined-or-queries-using-android-parse

Comment: Thanks mate. I have done the job using OR query. :) @nasch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParseQuery notExpiredPosts = new ParseQuery("Post");
query.whereGreaterThan("expire_date", new Date());

ParseQuery noExpiredDate = new ParseQuery("Post");
query.doesNotExist("expire_date");

ParseQuery expiredDateQuery = ParseQuery.or(notExpiredPosts, noExpiredDate);

ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Post");
query.whereWithinMiles("location_point", my_point, 500);
query.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("objectId", "objectId", expiredDateQuery);
return query;
```

> [(NotExpiredPost || NoExpiredDate) & (location_point within 500 mile)]

This is what you want, isn't it?

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I have proposed some syntactic changes on your code. Thank you very much for your guideline, it helped a lot! :)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. Happy coding :)