# How can I do an OR query for the same database column using ParseQuery?

Tags: java, parse-platform, parse-server, parse4j

I have a query with several constraints:

```
ParseQuery < ParseObject > requestsQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstantsUtil.CLASS_REQUEST);
requestsQuery.whereContains(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_AUTHOR, currentUser.getObjectId());
requestsQuery.whereEqualTo(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_STATUS, "Approved");
requestsQuery.whereEqualTo(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_STATUS, "Rejected");
requestsQuery.whereEqualTo(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_READ, false);
try {
 List < ParseObject > requestsList = requestsQuery.find();
 return listSize(model, requestsList);
} catch (ParseException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

One of those constraints happens to be related to the same column in my database:

```
requestsQuery.whereEqualTo(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_STATUS, "Approved");
requestsQuery.whereEqualTo(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_STATUS, "Rejected");
```

The above does not seem to work. How can I do an OR query for the same database column using ParseQuery?

```
requestsQuery.whereEqualTo(ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_STATUS, "Rejected" || "Approved");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Combined "Or" Queries using Android Parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892973/multiple-combined-or-queries-using-android-parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ParseQuery#whereContainedIn`:

```
List<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();
vals.add("Rejected");
vals.add("Approved");
requestsQuery.whereContainedIn((ParseConstantsUtil.REQUEST_STATUS, vals);
```

See [api documentation](http://parse-community.github.io/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereContainedIn(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)) for more information.